# How do I hide the ignored tags tags

Tags: feature-request, tags

Is there a way to hide the "Ignored Tags" tags.  I'm already hiding questions tagged with my ignore tages, now I would like to hide the tags indicating which tags I've ignored (i.e the list of tags under the heading "Ignored Tags" on the right side of the page).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not currently possible, unless you do something fancy like writing a custom userscript to chop that menu off locally.

Besides, what if you learn jQuery some day, and decide you want to stop ignoring `[jquery]`?

Comment: You visit the "tags" tab in your profile and un-ignore it. Of course, that requires a tags tab to be created, but it makes far more sense having ignored tags limited to a profile tab instead of wasting space on the homepage (and other question lists).

Comment: @Peter There is the "prefs" tab to do exactly that...

Comment: There we go then - no extra tab needed, just remove the ignored tags listing on the home page (replace it with a link to the prefs) and a whole bunch of space is saved. (And probably a db query too.)

Comment: @Peter There are some advantages to it being there, though. For example, if you only want to temporarily ignore tags, just to make a quick filter of what's immediately visible. Much easier to do it on the same page than to navigate to the profile, change it, and navigate back to whereever you were.

Comment: How often is that the desired functionality? (I'm guessing the SO team could measure that, assuming they log create/delete of ignored tags) Default functionality should cater for the majority, with other useful functionality as a preference (easy to add a "show ignored tags on homepage" checkbox to prefs tab).

Comment: There is some (new?) user preference, *Hide Ignored Tags*.

Comment: @Arjan, the OP is already using "hide ignored tags"; this question is about removing the sidebar box that lists the currently ignored tags.

Comment: Aha! So that preference is [not too new either](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange/59446#59446) then. Silly me ;-)

Comment: Or more importantly, what if you still don't care about jQuery but have a one-off jQuery question that you're looking up for a friend?  Then you just explicitly search for `jquery`, of course.